# How to find partner role for account

Tags: sharing, partner-communities

Recently I enabled Partner Community for one of existing Accounts. As I noticed the new Role was created with the similar name of my Account - I assume this role can be used to share records with recently created Partner Account's employees (partner users)

Q: How to exactly determine Partner Community Role by Account Id? Is there any link between Partner Account and automatically created Role?

Comment: On Account, which related list are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Found the reference to partner account in UserRole object. So in order to get automatically created Group for Partner Account you will need to do something like:

```
UserRole portalRole = [SELECT ParentRoleId FROM UserRole WHERE 
    PortalAccountId = :portalAccount.Id 
    LIMIT 1];
Group partnerPortalGroup = [SELECT Id, Name, 
    DeveloperName, RelatedId, Type, Email 
    FROM Group WHERE 
    RelatedId = :portalRole.Id];
```